Optimize VBA Range Copy/Paste
I have this current code that copies and pastes values in a loop. It works fine, but it takes a long time to complete when there is a lot of data. I think there is a more efficient way to do this with .value, but I am needing some advice on how to implement.
Sub Looping()
Dim OFFSETDOWN As String
Dim OFFSETLEFT As String
Dim OFFSETRITE As String
Dim FILEDONE As String
OFFSETDOWN = 1
OFFSETLEFT = 0
FILEDONE = "Calculate"

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
Range("E5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
Range("A10").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

Do Until FILEDONE = ""
'OFFSETDOWN = 0
'OFFSETLEFT = 0
'OFFSETRITE = 1

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D14").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D15").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D10").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Results").Select

Range("D11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("J10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("J12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("J11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("d8").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("d3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("j26").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("j27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Emp Data").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -29).Select

FILEDONE = ActiveCell.Value
Loop


End Sub


I have tried implementing the .value method from other tutorials, but I have not been able to figure out how to properly implement it. Any help with improving this code and understanding this topic more would be greatly appreciated.

Another recommendation would be to avoid using Select.

Assigning value is more efficient than select/copy/paste. eg. Sheets("Results").Range("D1").Value = Sheets("Emp Data").Range("E5").Value.

Improve Macro-Recorder Code

Not tested!

Sub UpdateEmpData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const EMP_FIRST_ROW As Long = 12
    Const EMP_BLANK_INDEX As Long = 0
    
    Dim eColsRead() As Variant: eColsRead = VBA.Array( _
        "A", "B", "F", "G", "I", _
        "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", _
        "O")
    Dim rCellsWrite() As Variant: rCellsWrite = VBA.Array( _
        "D2", "D14", "D3", "D4", "D5", _
        "D6", "D13", "D15", "D8", "D10", _
        "D11")
    
    Dim rCellsRead() As Variant: rCellsRead = VBA.Array( _
        "J10", "J12", "J11", "D8", "D3", _
        "J26", "J27")
    Dim eColsWrite() As Variant: eColsWrite = VBA.Array( _
        "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", _
        "AC", "AD")
    
    ' Reference the objects (workbook and worksheets).

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ews As Worksheet: Set ews = wb.Sheets("Emp Data")
    Dim rws As Worksheet: Set rws = wb.Sheets("Results")
    
    ' Write...
    rws.Range("D1").Value = ews.Range("E5").Value
    
    ' Set the first row in Emp.
    Dim er As Long: er = EMP_FIRST_ROW
    
    ' Loop...
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    Do
        If Len(CStr(ews.Cells(er, eColsRead(EMP_BLANK_INDEX)).Value)) = 0 Then
            Exit Do ' when cell in column 'A' is blank
        End If
        ' Read from Emp, write to Results.
        For c = 0 To UBound(eColsRead)
            rws.Range(rCellsWrite(c)).Value = ews.Cells(er, eColsRead(c)).Value
        Next c
        ' Read from Results, write to Emp.
        For c = 0 To UBound(eColsWrite)
            ews.Cells(er, eColsWrite(c)).Value = rws.Range(rCellsRead(c)).Value
        Next c
        er = er + 1
    Loop

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Emp data updated.", vbInformation

End Sub

